# Robotic Micro Assembler Santa

Tags: robots, santa-claus

So it occurs to me one of the major logistical limitations that Santa runs into is the volume of gifts even more so than the weight...particularly once they are gift wrapped.  Think about how much empty space there is just in foot balls, basket balls, soccer balls, rugby balls etc etc.

Expanding that to all gifts there is just so much wasted space and from a logistician's perspective wasted space is a killer.

That all in mind consider this.

Santa is actually a very advanced robotic micro factory.  Rather than building presents all year long he instead travels to homes and like a giant, jolly, dressed in red, 3d printer creates the toys on site.

So my question is this, **What resources (type not volume)** would santa require to create the standard fare toys.  Electronics, balls, stuffed animals etc etc.

Santa's robotic form is able to keep virtually all known components in a liquid state within his frame and sleigh (he restocks his internal resources from the sleigh...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Enormous blocks of superheavy matter.

Seeing that Santa has already mastered the finer point of **bit-perfect nano-assembly**, it would not be a stretch to assume that he also had the capability to use **fission to break down feedstocks of pure trans-uranic isotopes** into component elements of lighter atomic weight.  He would use these as **building blocks** with which to create an infinite myriad of toys.

Keeping the **feedstock** for this process in hollowed compartments within his person or his accouterments would be laughably quaint for a being so technologically advanced.  No, Santa makes use of a [**pocket universe**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocket_universe) to store these incredibly *(and very possibly highly radioactive)* heavy reserves of matter.

---

While credit goes to the hard sci-fi author Charles Stross for seeding my brain with the basis of this answer in one of his novels -- the "cornucopia machines" in *Singularity Sky* -- I'm impressed with [the comment](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/32155/robotic-micro-assembler-santa#comment86189_32166) from user [Thucydides](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8572/thucydides), who independently came up with a reverse version *(building successive elements in the periodic table, going "upwards" from lighter to heavier elements, using fusion)*.

Answer (score 0):

We all know of it and we all use it yet do we all understand it? The answer my friend is the cloud... Aka iCloud Santa can afford buying more storage or does he use the elves? Then again I could be wrong perhaps the cloud is actually " the chemtrails " sorry conspiracy theorists

Comment: He uses real clouds, extracts deuterium from the water and uses a highly advanced fusion generator to provide the energy for the assembler and to create higher elements in the periodic table for the assembler to use. Once Santa reaches iron with the fusion reactor, there is no more energetic fusion possible, so the heavier elements are shipped in via wormhole from "the sack"